# Filter a file removing lines just with all 0

Tags: awk, sed

I need to remove rows from a file with all "0" in the differents columns
Example

|  | seq_1 | seq_2 | seq_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data_0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| data_1 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| data_2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| data_3 | 6 | 0 | 2 |

From the example, I need a new file just with the row of data_2. Because it has just all "0" numbers.

I was try using grep and awk but I dont know how to filter just between column $2:4

Comment: You said both and didn't provide expected output so - do you want to print a line of all 0s (`I need a new file just with the row of data_2. Because it has just all "0" numbers.`) or remove a line of all 0s (`I need to remove rows from a file with all "0"`)? Also, please format your sample input/output as Code Blocks (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), not a graphical representation.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can rely on field string representation:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $2$3$4=="000"' test.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: This wouldn't give correct results for lines with negative numbers that add up to 0.

Comment: @steffen 1) `for lines that have "00" in $2` - if going for far, the digits can be `1e10`, so the OP should denote such an extended requirements. I don't accept your claims; 2) `this is the only answer with an upvote` - it dosn't have an explicit upvote: it on `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'FNR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i!=0)next}1' file
```

Explained:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1 {           # process all data records
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)   # loop all data fields
        if($i!=0)        # once non-0 field is found
            next         # on to the next record
}1' file                 # output the header and all-0 records
```

Very poorly formated output as the sample data is in some kind of table format which it probably is not IRL:

```
  seq_1  seq_2  seq_3
data_2  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed, find lines matching a pattern of one or more spaces followed by a 0 (3 times) and if found print the line.

```
sed -nr '/\s+0\s+0\s+0/'p file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Or with awk, if columns 2, 3 and 4 are equal to a 0, print the line.

```
awk '{if ($2=="0" && $3=="0" && $4=="0"){print $0}}' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

EDIT: I ran the `time` command on these a bunch of times and the awk version is generally faster.  Could add up if you are searching a large file. Of course your mileage may vary!

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand You are right, i edited my post.